# How to filter on values above x number?

Tags: pandas

[here is an image of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix2iM.png)I am trying to calculate the percentage of students with a passing math score (70 or greater). The table I am using is school_data_complete.

I have tried just using a conditional on the column

```
passing_math= school_data_complete.[['math_score'] > 70]
passing_math.sum()

File "<ipython-input-42-5d92405eb6b2>", line 14
    passing_math= school_data_complete.[['math_score'] > 70]
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `passing_math= school_data_complete[['math_score'] > 70].copy()
`

Comment: Thanks I got: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Can you show us your sample data ?

Comment: Ok sure added to the description

Comment: passing_math= school_data_complete['math_score'] > 70

Comment: @GustavoGradvohl this code works but when i try to get a dataframe with thisvar as a column i get "0 True 1 False 2 False ".  an imgof the table being used is in the desc

Comment: To get the filtered dataframe just pass your new variable as in school_data_complete[passing_math]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i have fully understood the question but the first part you are looking for the conditional check for the `math_score` column which can be achieved as follows.

### Sampling DataFrame from your given dataset:

```
>>> df
   School ID  Student ID   budget gender grade  math_score  reading_score       school_name  size  student_name      type
0          0           0  1910635      M   9th          79             66  Huang High Shool  2917   Paul Bradly  District
1          0           1  1910635      M  12th          61             94  Huang High Shool  2917  Victor Smith  District
2          0           2  1910635      M  12th          60             90  Huang High Shool  2917      Kvin Rod  District
3          0           3  1910635      M  12th          58             67  Huang High Shool  2917   Dr. Richard  District
4          0           4  1910635      M  12th          82             71  Huang High Shool  2917       Nicol S  District
```

### result output:

```
>>> df [ df['math_score'] > 70 ]
   School ID  Student ID   budget gender grade  math_score  reading_score       school_name  size student_name      type
0          0           0  1910635      M   9th          79             66  Huang High Shool  2917  Paul Bradly  District
4          0           4  1910635      M  12th          82             71  Huang High Shool  2917      Nicol S  District
```

OR

```
>>> df.loc[df.math_score > 70]
   School ID  Student ID   budget gender grade  math_score  reading_score       school_name  size student_name      type
0          0           0  1910635      M   9th          79             66  Huang High Shool  2917  Paul Bradly  District
4          0           4  1910635      M  12th          82             71  Huang High Shool  2917      Nicol S  District
```

other way around to pass a boolean flag across the dataframe based on comparison value can be done as follows as `True` & `False`  ..

```
>>> df.assign(new_math=(df['math_score'] > 70))
   School ID  Student ID   budget gender grade  math_score  reading_score       school_name  size  student_name      type  new_math
0          0           0  1910635      M   9th          79             66  Huang High Shool  2917   Paul Bradly  District      True
1          0           1  1910635      M  12th          61             94  Huang High Shool  2917  Victor Smith  District     False
2          0           2  1910635      M  12th          60             90  Huang High Shool  2917      Kvin Rod  District     False
3          0           3  1910635      M  12th          58             67  Huang High Shool  2917   Dr. Richard  District     False
4          0           4  1910635      M  12th          82             71  Huang High Shool  2917       Nicol S  District      True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
passing_math= school_data_complete[school_data_complete['math_score'] > 70].copy()
```

Or

```
passing_math= school_data_complete.query('math_score>70')
```

---

```
(school_data_complete['math_score'] > 70).value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: Ok it went through but the value returned is "Student ID student_name gender grad..."

Comment: @Mr.Demagorgon`(school_data_complete['math_score'] > 70).value_counts(normalize=True)`